# How to get images dynamically From Odoo to banner image slide?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, dynamic, odoo-15, image-slider

I want to create a dynamic Image slider in Odoo15. I have seen many examples of creating product sliders in Odoo but no example of banner image sliders. I want to create image sliders like the below app store

https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/image_slider_10/

The user wants to add Images for the slider in the front end. I am able to achieve creating static image slider using the below example

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

Can anyone help me to create the dynamic banner image slider? Looking forward to the help.

thanks and regards

Nirmala Sudhir

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that Odoo 15 has Carousel integrated, I would suggest that you check the code in `odoo/addons/website/views/snippets/s_dynamic_snippet_carousel.xml`.

It's how they created their Carousel.

You better know that it's not the easiest thing to do to recreate nice snippets on Odoo, but once you get used to it it'll be ok :)

Important stuff are to create your kind of snippet (check the file I mentioned above), the links to `000.js` and `000.scss`, and add this snippet in `web_editor.snippets` (you can check examples in `odoo/addons/website/views/snippets/snippets.xml`)

Hope it helped :)